# Dropdowns btn-group

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

estoy intentando dar tamaño fijo a todos los primeros button del btn-group,en un Dropdowns.

El problema es que se ajusta al tamaño del texto, y lo que quiero es fijar un tamaño, no importando del texto que se ingrese. Gracias por su ayuda.

---

```
    <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-large"  onclick='window.open("http://google.com.pe"); return false'>Buscadores</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                      </button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item">Sistema de información gerencial.</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="btn-group ">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick='window.open("https://yahoo.es"); return false'>SG</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                      </button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item">Sistema de trámite documentario institucional.</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Podrias añadir el codigo completo? para ver como estas metiendo los buttons

Comment: Para que el ancho fijo de los botones se aplique, tu botón por lo menos debe de tener un valor de display igual a inline-block, es probable que por eso tu ancho no se este aplicando.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con css.

Escribe una regla, por ejemplo `.btn-custom { width: 120px }`
Y agrégale esa clase al botón que quieras que tenga ese tamaño. Y así lo puedes aplicar para otros elementos.

```css
.btn-custom { width: 120px }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-large btn-custom" onclick='window.open("http://google.com.pe"); return false'>Buscadores</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item">Sistema de información gerencial.</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group ">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-custom" onclick='window.open("https://yahoo.es"); return false'>SG</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item">Sistema de trámite documentario institucional.</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fue lo que inicialmente hice, pero lamentablemente no se aplica, se sigue ajustando el tamaño del boton de acuerdo al texto.

Comment: @ElvisUceda Actualicé mi respuesta con un ejemplo que hice utilizando el código que compartiste. Me cuentas si te sirve.